# Is it possible to manually set istream fail bit in C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, iostream, friend

I've made this class:

```
class object {
  // data...
 public:
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& in, object& o) {
    char c, d;
    in >> c >> d;
    if (c == d) {
      /*set the fail bit some how*/
      in.putback(d);
      in.putback(c);
    } else
      o.set_data(c, d);
    return in;
  }
};
```

I was looking at the documentation (not well) but couldn't find a proper way to set the fail bit. The reason I care is I'd like to be able to `while(std::cin>>obj)/*do stuff*/;` like one can do with an int. But if I currently do this there would be an infinite loop any time there was an error. `-_-` Is setting the fail bit possible or am I going to have to work with this problem a different way?

Comment: `in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [setstate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/setstate). Note you should put it after the invoke of [putback](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/putback), otherwise the chars won't be `putback`ed successfully because the stream has been in an error condition. i.e.

```
if (c==d) {

    in.putback(d);
    in.putback(c);

    /*set the fail bit some how*/
    in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
}
```

Answer (score 11):

You can set the failbit of an input stream using the [basic_ios::setstate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/setstate) function:

```
in.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
```